# Least expensive way to insert unique rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with columns defined under a unique index. When inserting data into the table, I'm currently not checking to see if a matching row already exists, instead letting MySQL handle it.

Is this the preferred approach? I mean, I could add a SELECT to check for dupe rows before insert, but it seems that would be more expensive from performance perspective, since maybe like 5-10% of inserts will trigger a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just let MySQL figure it out. It already knows what the next possible value is and will pick it much faster than you can.

Not only could your `select` method fail, it also involves two round-trips to the server instead of one. Not to mention that just letting the server figure it out gives it more opportunity to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a "ON DUPLICATE KEY" syntax that is pretty useful:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html